# Embed a timer in a sharepoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

We have a SharePoint 2010 list with a field to capture hours worked.

Is there a control or other mechanism that would allow me to place a timer to the right of the `Actual Hours Done` field?

[image]

In page edit more, it would:

- could be stopped/started with a keyboard combination
- update the `Actual Hours Done` field when actuated (play pushed)
- update the `Development Completed Date` with the date the pause button was pressed

In list mode, it would:

- could be stopped/started with a mouse click
- operate independently of the other timers
- update SP's data asynchronously

[image]

Are either of these features possible?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using JavaScript `timeout`. But this solution can be easily compromised.

More elegant solution involves creating a webservice which has two methods `Start` and `Stop`.

When a user click on the play button - This should invoke the `Start` service call. This call will internally updates the list item with the current date time value. Then one screen you can use JavaScript to decrements the value and display it.

When a user click on the pause button - This should invoke the `Stop` service call. This call will internally updates the list item with the current date time value. The service call will get the time difference and make sure its correct. It also return the actual value back to the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an additional nullable column for 'Current Work Start' and update that with the timestamp that a start button is clicked (InfoPath or custom forms, just edit, display a message or change an icon and then keep form open). When the stop button is clicked, calculate the difference between the 'Current Work Start' and now. Update your time spent column (total logged minutes) with the original amount + the difference in minutes. Clear out the 'Current Work Start' column to complete the transaction.